# count of unique values in one column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate this dataframe I have with this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'A', 4: 'A'},
    'Col1': {0: True, 1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: True},
    'Col2': {0: 'x', 1: 'y', 2: 'y', 3: 'x', 4: 'y'}
})
```

```
  Name   Col1 Col2
0    A   True    x
1    B  False    y
2    B  False    y
3    A  False    x
4    A   True    y
```

The result I am trying to get is a count of every unique for col1 and col2 based on the name column

```
Name True False x  y
  A   2    1    2  1
  B   0    2    0  2
```

I was able to count some of the columns manually...but I feel like there is probably a much more efficient way to do this using pandas

```
table = df["Name"].unique().tolist()
for i in table:
    rows = df[df['Name'] == i]
    number_true = (rows["Col1"] == "True").sum()
    number_false = (rows["Col1"] == "False").sum()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas-get-dummies) + [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-sum):

```
new_df = (
    pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
        .groupby('Name', as_index=False)
        .sum()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
  Name  Col1_False  Col1_True  Col2_x  Col2_y
0    A           1          2       2       1
1    B           2          0       0       2
```

---

With no prefix or prefix_sep:

```
new_df = (
    pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'],
                   prefix_sep='', prefix='')
        .groupby('Name', as_index=False)
        .sum()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
  Name  False  True  x  y
0    A      1     2  2  1
1    B      2     0  0  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) your df using your `Name` column as ids, which will allow you to [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) keeping using your `Name` column as your index.

```
df = (
    pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'])
    .pivot_table(columns='value', aggfunc='count', index='Name', values='variable', fill_value=0)
)
df
```

out:

| value | False | True | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name |  |  |  |  |
| A | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

```
# Remove name attribute for columns
df.columns.name = None
df
```

out:

| Name | False | True | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

---

Edited to include @henry-ecker's comment.

Comment: If you specify the `values` arg of `pivot_table` you can skip the `droplevel` step: `.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='value', values='variable', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)`